# The problem is if they believe what I said

Tags: whether-if

"The problem is whether they believe what I said." is a correct sentence. How about "The problem is if they believe what I said."? This sentence is less commonly used but still OK?

Comment: Yup, they both work. I would think 2nd example is more commonly used, but I have no support for that claim.

Answer (score 3):

Your first sentence involves three ellipses. One of these is implicit in the *whether* construction:

> ... whether they believe what I said **or not**.

The other omissions are not implicit in the sentence; they must be inferred by your hearer or reader from the discourse context. For instance, your particular example might represent:

> The problem [**for us**] is [**to discover**] whether they believe what I said.
>   The problem [**for them**] is [**to decide**] whether they believe what I said.

In this sort of *whether* clause<sup>†</sup> it is often possible to substitute *if* for *whether*—when we are speaking of a question, for instance:

> The question is **whether** they believe what I said (or not).
>   The question if **if** they believe what I said (or not).

At first glance, there is no reason that *if* could not be substituted in your question:

> The problem for us is to discover **if** they believe what I said.

I think most NS would agree that that is a well-formed sentence. However, it appears that this sentence does not occur, or occurs only very rarely, with ellipsis of the term represented here by *to discover*. I have just gone through the first hundred Google hits on “the problem is if”, and *not one* has the form of your sentence.

Why? I have a guess, but it is no more than that.

I think it is because *the problem is if* has a competing use in which the *if* heads a conditional clause which defines the ‘problem’ as contingent.

> I’ve just told them that it wasn’t me who smashed up their car but Joe. The problem is **if they believe what I said** they’re probably going to go beat Joe to a bloody pulp.

The sequence *The problem is if* leads hearers and readers to expect a sentence like that; so to avoid confusion, speakers and writers avoid it. That doesn’t mean it’s wrong or ungrammatical; just that there is good reason for you to avoid it, too.

---

<sup>†</sup> Some linguists distinguish this sort of *Wh-* clause from other sorts and call it an “embedded question”.